# How to GroupBy a Dataframe in Pandas and keep Columns

Tags: python, pandas

given a dataframe that logs uses of some books like this:

```
Name   Type   ID
Book1  ebook  1
Book2  paper  2
Book3  paper  3
Book1  ebook  1
Book2  paper  2
```

I need to get the count of all the books, keeping the other columns and get this:

```
Name   Type   ID    Count
Book1  ebook  1     2
Book2  paper  2     2
Book3  paper  3     1
```

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You want the following:

```
In [20]:
df.groupby(['Name','Type','ID']).count().reset_index()

Out[20]:
    Name   Type  ID  Count
0  Book1  ebook   1      2
1  Book2  paper   2      2
2  Book3  paper   3      1
```

In your case the 'Name', 'Type' and 'ID' cols match in values so we can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on these, call [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count) and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index).

An alternative approach would be to add the 'Count' column using `transform` and then call `drop_duplicates`:

```
In [25]:
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['ID'].transform('count')
df.drop_duplicates()

Out[25]:
    Name   Type  ID  Count
0  Book1  ebook   1      2
1  Book2  paper   2      2
2  Book3  paper   3      1
```

Comment: This seems to work, but If we had many more columns (as I have in other dataframes), wouldn't this hurt performance? Also, it is not very intuitive.

Comment: The problem here is that grouping will reduce the amount of information so it won't necessarily yield your desired df in one go, I've updated my answer to show how it could be done in 2 steps which is better to understand

Answer (score 123):

I think `as_index=False` should do the trick.

```
df.groupby(['Name','Type','ID'], as_index=False).count()
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer and works for other summary stats.

Answer (score 33):

If you have many columns in a df it makes sense to use `df.groupby(['ID']).agg(Count=('ID', 'count'),...)`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49783240/5838180). The `.agg()` function allows you to choose what to do with the columns you don't want to apply operations on. If you just want to keep them (or more precisely to keep the first entries in them), use `.agg(Count=('ID', 'count'), col1=('col1', 'first'), col2=('col2', 'first'),...)`. Instead of `'first'`, you can also apply `'sum'`, `'mean'` and others.

Comment: I use this because it gives custom names to new calculated columns.

Comment: @SteveScott I actually didn't know about the option to give custom names to new columns. Can you provide an example? I will be certainly using it, I frequently come back to this answer to look up the exact syntax

Comment: @NeStack `.agg(col1_sum=('col1', 'sum'), col2_avg=('col2', 'mean'))`

Answer (score 4):

SIMPLEST WAY

`df.groupby(['col1', 'col1'], as_index=False).count()`. Use `as_index=False` to retain column names. The default is `True`.

Also you can use `df.groupby(['col_1', 'col_2']).count().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value_counts()` as well:

```
df.value_counts().reset_index(name= 'Count')
```

Output:

```
    Name   Type  ID  Count
0  Book1  ebook   1      2
1  Book2  paper   2      2
2  Book3  paper   3      1
```