# Losing keys in pandas dataframe when after using groupby

Tags: python, r, group-by, aggregate

I'm pretty new to Python and I just encountered a problem.

`mini_agg` is my original `pandas.dataframe` and I'm trying to group
it by 2 columns.

```
trial = mini_agg.groupby(['date','product','product_type_1','product_type_2','product_type_3','product_type_4']).sum()

print mini_agg.shape
print trial.shape
```

output:

> (2965909, 10)
>    (499281, 4)

Furthermore I cannot access the keys by which I grouped by. 
In R I do obtain my column back when using aggregate.

Can you please help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include the mini_agg values to your provided code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to GroupBy a Dataframe in Pandas and keep Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569549/how-to-groupby-a-dataframe-in-pandas-and-keep-columns)

Just found the answer I didn't find with my previous queries:

```
trial = mini_agg.groupby(['date','product','product_type_1','product_type_2','product_type_3','product_type_4']).sum().reset_index()
```

It is sufficient to add `.reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

I expected mini_agg values to be provided however I suppose it's a combination of two one-dimensional labeled data structures. So as you mentioned mini_agg is a  `pandas.dataframe` and as you must know `DataFrame` Like `Series` has a possibility to accept another `DataFrame` as input:

Therefore, If mini_agg to be like:

```
import pandas as pd
FRAME= {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['product_type_1', 'product_type_2', 'product_type_3']),
'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['product_type_1', 'product_type_2', 'product_type_3', 'product_type_4'])}
mini_agg = pd.DataFrame(FRAME)
```

So,

```
trial = pd.DataFrame(mini_agg, index=['date','product','product_type_1','product_type_2','product_type_3','product_type_4'], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
```