# How to GroupBy a Dataframe in Pandas and keep whole fields in the output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-analysis

I want groups based on three columns, but keep the original columns in the output(6 column).

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569549/how-to-groupby-a-dataframe-in-pandas-and-keep-columns) Actually did not help me. it just had three columns and grouped based on those three columns.

this is a sample of my `original` data frame :

```
   Clinic Number  Question Text  Answer Text Answer Date     year  month dayofyear
1       1        bathing            No    2006/7/1     2006    1         7
2       1        dressing           No    2006/7/1     2006    1         7
3       1        feeding            NO    2006/7/1     2006    1         7
4       1        housekeeping       No    2006/7/1     2006    1         7
5       1        medications        No    2006/7/1     2006    1         7
6       2        bathing            No    2006/1/1     2006    1         1
7       2        dressing           Yes   2006/1/1     2006    1         1
8       2        feeding            Yes   2006/1/1     2006    1         1
9       2        housekeeping       Yes   2006/1/1     2006    1         1
10      2        medications        No    2006/1/1     2006    1         1
```

I want to group by `[clinicNumber,Answer Text, Year,month]`,
but I need other columns like `Answer Date and question Text, yearOfday` column, because later I want to do some calculation on them.

What I did:
this is the group by I am using on this dataframe to reach my goal. the problem is that there is no `Answer date ,yearofyear ...` in the output.

```
grouped = data.groupby(['Clinic Number','year','month','Answer Text']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

the output of this group by is like this:

```
 Clinic Number    year   month   Answer Text  counts
0         1       1999     5          No       6
1         1       2000    10          No       6
2         1       2000     2          No       6
3         1       2001     9          Yes       6
4         1       2002     2          Yes       8
5         1       2003     2          No       8
6         1       2004     4          No       8
7         1       2014     6          No       2
8         1       2015    10          No       2
5         2       2003     2          No       8
6         2       2004     4          No       8
7         2       2014     6          No       2
8         2       2015    10          No       2
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use `groupby` with `transform` and set it to a new column in existing dataframe.

```
data['counts'] = (data.groupby(['Clinic Number',
                                'year',
                                'month',
                                'Answer Text'])['Clinic Number']
                      .transform('size'))

data = data.sort_values(['Client Number','Answer Date'])
```

Output:

```
    Clinic Number Question Text Answer Text Answer Date  year  month  dayofyear  counts
1               1       bathing          No    2006/7/1  2006      1          7       4
2               1      dressing          No    2006/7/1  2006      1          7       4
3               1       feeding          NO    2006/7/1  2006      1          7       1
4               1  housekeeping          No    2006/7/1  2006      1          7       4
5               1   medications          No    2006/7/1  2006      1          7       4
6               2       bathing          No    2006/1/1  2006      1          1       2
7               2      dressing         Yes    2006/1/1  2006      1          1       3
8               2       feeding         Yes    2006/1/1  2006      1          1       3
9               2  housekeeping         Yes    2006/1/1  2006      1          1       3
10              2   medications          No    2006/1/1  2006      1          1       2
```

Comment: Smart. why I did not think about this approach :|||

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi Thank you.   Happy coding!

Comment: Just one thing @Scott Boston, Now I can not apply sorting on this. Is there any difference between this code for the sorting and previous one?. I want to do sorting on date. thanks for your time :)

Comment: Nope, sorting should be exactly the same.  this is the original dataframe with one addtional column.

Comment: May I ak you to update the answer with sorting please

Comment: Actually I need the sort for each Clinic Number, I mean for each clinic Number, its date should be sort. with this approach it totally look at the data frame and sort it

Comment: FYI... you don't have Answer Text in your original dataframe, so I can't test and verify this code.

Comment: You are right @Scott Boston. I just added that column :)

Comment: may I ask you please have alook on this question . Do you have any idea of that?  thanks for your time :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862198/date-range-for-six-monthly-in-pandas