# Groupby in Pandas for dataframe and not series

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
             ID      Date    Element  Data_Value Month_Day
143873  USW00014833 2005-01-02  TMIN    -0.6    01-02
74019   USW00094889 2005-01-02  TMIN    -0.6    01-02
112671  USC00200032 2005-01-02  TMAX    12.2    01-02
```

I want to group by the "Month_Day" column and sort by the values in "Data_Value", but still keep the dataframe format and the other columns.

I have tried the following code:

```
df = df.groupby('Month_Day')['Data_Value'].sort_values()
```

However, by this method I lose the other columns and the output is a series(I believe).

Any advice?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use groupby. As in the link bellow, you need to groupby using list of columns that you want to keep and then call reset_index()

[How to GroupBy a Dataframe in Pandas and keep Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569549/how-to-groupby-a-dataframe-in-pandas-and-keep-columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort on two columns:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Month_Day', 'Data_Value'])
```